# JavaScript: Login on website using autohotkey

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, autohotkey, form-submit

I am new to javascript and autohotkey programmation. I am trying to log into a website, but so far I am unable to submit the form properly.

Here is the HTML of the page :

```html
     <form ng-show="!maintenanceCritique" class="form ng-pristine ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid ng-valid-required" name="formMobile" ng-submit="login(formMobile)" novalidate="" touch-submit="">


             <div style="padding-top:30px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px">

                  <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Code permanent</span><br>
                  <input style="width:100%" name="codePermanent" ng-model="user.codePermanent" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]{4}(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|6[3-9]|[78][0-9]|9[0-3]|99)([0,5][1-9]|[1,6][012]|13|63)[0-9]{4}$/" maxlength="12" tabindex="1" placeholder="(ex. : ABDC12034566)" autofocus="" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched">

                  <br><br>
                  <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;NIP</span><br>
                  <input style="width:100%" type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{5}$/" maxlength="5" tabindex="2" placeholder="(ex. : 12345)" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched">

                  <div>
                     <!-- ngIf: formMobile.codePermanent.$error.required && formMobile.password.$error.required && submitted -->
                     <!-- ngIf: err -->
                  </div>
                  <br>

                   <div style="text-align:right">
                      <button class="btn btn-default btn-inverse btn-lg btn-login text-uppercase" type="submit" click="submitted=true" tabindex="3">
                        <span style="height:60%;width:140px;text-transform:none;font-family:'Conv_Dosis',arial,sans-serif; font-size:100%">Connexion</span>
                     </button>
                   </div>
     </form>
  </div>
```

And here is my code :

```
WB := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
WB.Visible := True
WB.Navigate(URL)

loop
If !WB.busy
 break
sleep 1000


WB.document.getElementsByName("codePermanent")[0].focus()
WB.document.getElementsByName("codePermanent")[0].value := "username"
sleep 1000
WB.document.getElementsByName("password")[0].focus()
WB.document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value := "password"

form := WB.document.getElementsByName("form")[0]
form.method := "post"
form.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
wb.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default btn-inverse btn-lg btn-login text-uppercase")[0].click()
```

This will click the submit button if that button is the first one on the page with that class name. Remeber, [getElementsByClassName()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) returns a [nodelist](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp), so you have to specify which specific element you're wanting to click by including its reference in the square brackets.

From there, it's just a matter of using the `.click()` method.

If this answers your question, please mark the question answered.
If not, let me know so we can get it answered.

Comment: I have tried it and it does not log me in, unfortunately

Comment: You could try clicking it via jquery by passint it through the address bar. See if this works: `wb.Navigate(JavaScript:$('input[type=submit]').click())`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you never get the form element. You are trying to access it by its tag name, but you are using the getElementsByName method.  Instead you should use the getElementsByTagName method:

```
WB := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
WB.Visible := True
WB.Navigate(URL)

While WB.readyState!=4 || WB.document.readyState!="complete" || WB.busy
   Sleep 50

WB.document.getElementsByName("codePermanent")[0].value := "username"
WB.document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value := "password"
Sleep 1000
form := WB.document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0] ; TagName - not Name
form.method := "post"
form.submit()
```